# Accessing an object in java

Tags: java, object

I created a java class, say  `class1` to define an object that gets stored somewhere in the memory. And I want to access that obect using an another class, say `class2`. How do i access that very object and its intances I defined in `class1` from `class2`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in Java we usually use class names that start with a capital letter (`Class1` and `Class2`)

```
public class Class1 {
    //...
}

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
    }
}
```

This means that you access an object of Class1 inside Class2 via a constructor.

In my example I am using the default constructor, but you can also define other constructors with parameters in your Class1 like:

```
public class Class1 {
    private String s1, s2;
    public Class1(String s1, String s2) {
        // do something (in general assign s1 and s2 to attributes s1 and s2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a phone, and want to let your friend use that phone. What do you do? You give it the phone, right? Same with Java objects.

```
Foo foo = new Foo(); 
Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
// now bar has a reference to the foo object, and can use it in every method.
```

or

```
Foo foo = new Foo(); 
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
// now doSomethingWithFoo() has a reference to the foo object, and can use it.
```

To be more concrete:

```
Phone phone = new Phone();
Friend friend = new Friend();
friend.makeAPhoneCall(phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make field that has type `class1` inside `class2` like this:

```
public class class2{
    class1 my_obj;

    //other code
}
```

and you can access it like this:

```
class2 my_obj_c2 = new class2();
my_obj_c2.my_obj = new class1();
```

Also you can access that object via method:

```
class2 ex_obj = my_obj_c2.getClass1Obj();
```

where this method has this declaration:

```
public class1 getClass1Obj(){
    return my_obj;
}
```

Use method if you don't have or don't want to use lower priviledges on this class1 object inside class2.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, in class2 you can define property of class1.

```
public class Class2 {
   private Class1 myclass;

   public void setmyclass(Class1 myclass1) {
   this.myclass = myclass1;
   }
   public Class1 getmyclass() {
   return this.myclass;
   }
}
```

And then main or wherever you want you just.

```
Class1 mycreatedclass1 = new Class1();
Class2 mycreatedclass2 = new Class2();
mycreatedclass1.setmyclass(mycreatedclass2);
```